# Implement stale-while-revalidate using Retrofit and okhttp

Tags: android, http, retrofit, okhttp

Does anyone know how to implement stale-while-revalidate using Retrofit and okhttp in Android?

Comment: It's really difficult because Retrofit mostly assumes one response per call, and stale-while-revalidate requires two. You might be able to do something that uses an Rx Observable that emits either one or two times.

Comment: Hi @JesseWilson, thanks for the guidance, I was trying to implement something similar what Jake Wharton suggested here: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1722 . Unfortunately, I'm getting unsupported exception while using the default method. Can you point me in the right direction?